# Alert box ..on and off

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Hi I am using alertdialog..and when the user clicks ok it has to restart the same activty (GAME)
and when he clicks no it has to go to the main menu.. but when i click ok..2 activities 
are running simultaneously and when i clock no..and come back here..the dialog is still present!
Help! This is the snippet

```
  AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertbox.setMessage("oops! wrong answer! wanna play again?");
    alertbox.setPositiveButton("Yea sure!",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                   Intent game = new Intent("nik.trivia.GAME");
                    startActivity(game);
                    finish();
});





alertbox.setNegativeButton("Nope! take me to the main menu",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    Intent menu = new Intent("nik.trivia.MENU");
                    startActivity(menu);
                    finish();


                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `dismiss()` on your `AlertDialog` after the user has clicked a button.

EDIT: just place this line of code:

```
   arg0.dismiss();
```

inside the `onClick` method.

Comment: alertbox.dismiss() its telling it as an invalid method

Comment: everything now is working fine..but still dialog is not going away when I call the same intent from the menu.. how is this possible? and what should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to start only an instance of this activity you have to set the flag as `singleTask` and get the intent in the `onNewIntent()` method.

Edited:

Set singleTask as flag of the activity in the manifest file in order not to have many instances of the same activity and add this to your activity:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);   
    setIntent(intent);
    // Do here whatver you want. This method is similar to the onCreate() method.
}
```

Comment: I should do this with negative alert? whereexactly should I start the menu intent, close the dialog and finish the activty? can you show that in my code please?

Answer (score 0):

in your case you can add:
alertbox.dismiss()

when you call finish() it is on the whole activity not just the dialog

EDIT:

```
  public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                Intent menu = new Intent("nik.trivia.MENU");
                startActivity(menu);

                arg0.dismiss();
                finish();
```

or you can juste declare alertbox protected:

```
protected AlertDialog alertDialog
```

and the n you will be able to call dismis on it from everywhere

Comment: alertbox.dismiss() its telling it as an invalid method

Comment: It dismisses when I click the setNegativeButton but when i select this activity from the menu..it restores its previous state

Comment: everything now is working fine..but still dialog is not going away when I call the same intent? how is this possible? and what should I do ?

Comment: hard to tell because the entire code is not present but one thing I know is you have to call dismiss() and finish() in both cases (negative and positive). You have to understand is when you launch your second activity with the intent the current activity (the first one) goes to onPause() state, then onStop then if you call it again from another activity or press the back button the activity comes back trough onResume state and not onCreate. Here is more info on activity lifecicle: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html